# object HTMLInputElement error with .value

Tags: javascript, dom, input

I have a problem with returning "[object HTMLInputElement]", this is my code:
HTML:
`<input type="text" id="numb7">`
JavaScript:
`var numb7 = document.getElementById("numb7").value;`
When I alert numb7 it returns:
[object HTMLInputElement]
Can anyone help me?

For the full code: [Full Code](http://pastebin.com/qUnJcW0c)

Comment: That's not an error. Also, if that's really what your code looks like, that would not happen.

Comment: only omitting `.value` would do that ...`alert(document.getElementById("numb7"))`

Comment: I copied and pasted it. It's working properly. Can you post full code.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's an old MSIE compatibility feature where all `id` and `name` attributes are added to the global object. Try giving your variable (or `id`) a different name.

Comment: When I change the id to "numbEnd", I get this error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: numb7

Comment: @user3722860: I don't think the scope of the variable `numb7` in `calc()` extends to the `calcNumbA()` function. You need the full `document.getElementById(...)` reference.